# Interactive Java Compiler and Display

Tags: java

Is there a website or program that displays the compiled program and shows you the changes that you make to your source code? (Like it shows your source code on the left and your program on the right with changes that you are making to it in your source code.)

Comment: 'Realtime' has a specific meaning in computing, and that isn't it. Please use standard terminology correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you're searching for an application that can show code and support runtime changes
eclipse can do that

Answer (score 0):

A window builder can do this. in Eclipse, `right click on your swing file, open in Window-Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is essentially built around this. Eclipse also supports this via various official and unofficial plugins.